# How can I just draw outline around objects in images as shown in this image

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing, borders

[image]

I just want to know that How can I enter colourful borders(red and yellow in above image) to objects in my image also...
And also if there is any ios/android app to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Photoshop you would cut out the figures, using for example the pen tool. Then once they are on their own layers apply the "outer glow" layer style using the desired colours.

For someone experienced with photoshop, and depending on the complexity of the figures, it would be a five minute job.

The takeaway for you here is to google "Photoshop outer glow"